# Can I tag in Apache Subversion with NAnt?

Tags: svn, tags, nant, build-script

I need to build multiple environments and tag them in [Apache Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) using a [NAnt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAnt) script. Is there a way that I can use NAnt to create the tags in Apache Subversion with a variable I supply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I haven't worked with nant myself, but given that there is an [<exec>](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) task, you should be able to use it to run the Subversion CLI client with something like:

```
<exec program="svn" commandline='copy http://myserver/svn/trunk "http://myserver/svn/tags/${tag_name}"' />
```

(I used [this example](http://untidy.net/blog/2006/08/21/subversion-revision-number-in-nant/) as a model.)

On Windows, I always install the [Slik SVN binaries](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/) and add the installation's `bin` directory to my PATH.

Comment: Thanks, this appears the way to go. I was looking for a task like snvant but I don't believe it exists on the nant side. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, there is the `svn` task in [the nantcontrib project](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/svn.html), though I would say the documentation is a bit thin.